# how to show two column at each row in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

could you please tell me how to  show two column at each row in angular ?.I need to show two column in each row .I am trying to show only two row in each slide .If there is more the 4 items I need to show item on ion-slide. I will explain more

1) First I take only four objects in arrays .I need to show two in each row as shown in image

2) If there is more then four objects I need to scroll horizontally  using  ion-slide ..Actually In my demo it is showing only one column on each row why ?

here is my code
http://play.ionic.io/app/95a2d932f578

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ion-slide-box>
        <ion-slide>
            <div class="row" ng-repeat="d in data">
                <div class="col col-50">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                            {{d.name}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slide-box>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made a small demo for you as per the requirement,

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/t8v73b?p=preview)

**Contoller**

```
$scope.items = [{
    name1: "Product 1",
    img1: "https://placehold.it/100x100",
    content1: "Awesome",
    name2: "Product 2",
    img2: "https://placehold.it/100x100",
    content2: "cool",
}, {
    name1: "Product 3",
    img1: "https://placehold.it/100x100",
    content1: "Fantstic",
    name2: "Product 4",
    img2: "https://placehold.it/100x100",
    content2: "Not bad",
}, {
    name1: "Product 5",
    img1: "https://placehold.it/100x100",
    content1: "Good",
    name2: "Product 6",
    img2: "https://placehold.it/100x100",
    content2: "best",
}]
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="item in items" style="margin:5px auto">
    <div class="col col-50">
        <div class="div-img-device">
            <img class="img-device" ng-src="{{item.img1}}"> {{item.name1}}
            <br>{{item.content1}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-50">
        <div class="div-img-device">
            <img class="img-device" ng-src="{{item.img2}}"> {{item.name2}}
            <br>{{item.content2}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.div-img-device {
        background-color: #4F8CA5;
        margin: 0;
        autoborder: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 4px;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
 }

 .img-device {
        width: 100%;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        padding-top: 20px;
 }
```

If you need more features.Please let me know

Comment: thanks for ansering ..But I need if there is six object then it start horizontal scrolling instead of vertical .That why I use ion-slide

Comment: I need to show four box on one page .and if there is more than four page then it scroll horizontally

Comment: as i give you object in demo

Comment: you can take any type of object ..I just making a demo

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code something like below which take advantage of $index of angularjs.

```
<ion-slide-box>
 <ion-slide>
  <ion-scroll zooming="true" direction="y" style="height: 500px">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="d in data" ng-switch on="$index % 2">
        <div class="col col-50" ng-switch-when="0">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                  {{d.name}}
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
     <div class="col col-50" ng-show="data[$index+1]">
            <div class="card" ng-switch-when="0">
                <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                  {{data[$index+1].name}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </ion-scroll>
</ion-slide>
```

Please follow below link to see it in action.

[play.ionic.io](http://play.ionic.io/app/65a261a8188c)

Comment: what happen when data is more then 4 or four objects

Comment: You can add scroll inside  <ion-slide> like <ion-scroll zooming="true" direction="y" style="height: 500px">. I have updated the example in play.iconic

Comment: I try but it not work ..Andcould you please explain your logic above ?

Comment: could you please make one more play ionic ...!! could you please explain more how you can achieve using ng-switch ?

Comment: Updated my example in same play.iconic.

Comment: it is scrolling vertically not horizontally..I just want if data is more it scroll horizontally using ion-slide ..nit ion scroll which is scrolling horizontally

Comment: http://play.ionic.io/app/d17d884a51c3 please check it not working ..I think we are not a proper or best way